# Inserting Data From a Excel Column Throughout the Row

Tags: excel

I am trying to insert a value in a column into 3 other columns in the same row.

Basically inserting `A1` into a string in columns `B1`, `G1` and `F1`.

---

**row1** would have:

`A1= LSL3007, B1= [SyrupRoom]LSL0201.Fault.sts_tripped, G1= [SyrupRoom]LSL0201`

and I would like to `replace` the `LSL0201` with `LSL3007`.

---

**row2** would have

`A2= LSL3007, B2= [SyrupRoom]LSL0201.Fault.sts_tripped, G2= [SyrupRoom]LSL0201`

and I would like to `replace` the `LSL0201` with `LSL3008`.

---

This goes on for about 500 rows.

Comment: Do you mean for A2 = LSL3008?

Comment: Correct, sorry about that

Comment: Also, can you give an example of the F column? And it literally the same the whole way down. I ask because if it is then I don't need to search for the string, and can just edit it using substring methods.

Comment: I can't give a true answer until you reply, but you can use the substitute method. It should go like this: click on B1. Type =SUBSTITUTE("[SyrupRoom]LSL0201.Fault.sts_tripped", "LSL0201", A1). You can then drag this formula down using the little box on the bottom right. The parameters for the subsitue formula are (original text, text to replace, text to replace with)

Comment: F column is going to be F= Display "PPT Digital Input" /T [SyrupRoom]LSL0201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment you can use the Substitute function.

Substitute has 3 parameters, the original string, the string you want to change, and the string you want to replace it with. It is basically find and replace.

Since you have 3 columns you will have to do this 3 times.

As a case example say `A1 = LSL3007`, and `B1 = [SyrupRoom]LSL0201.Fault.sts_tripped`.
When you click on `B1`, `[SyrupRoom]LSL0201.Fault.sts_tripped`, will show up in the textbox (function box) at the top of the page.

Replace this with:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("[SyrupRoom]LSL0201.Fault.sts_tripped", "LSL0201", A1)
```

Remember to be careful with quotation marks! It should then fix the string in `B1` as you want it.

To apply this to the entire column, you can click on `B1`, then drag the little box on the bottom right of the cell, or double click on it to apply this formula to the entire column.

Assuming all of the values in the columns are identical as you stated in your question, this should work.

Repeat this for each column, replacing the first string with the unique string for that column.

One last thing, since column `F` has quotes within the string, you will have to escape them by using double quotes, so it will look like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("Display ""PPT Digital Input"" /T [SyrupRoom]LSL0201", "LSL0201",A1)
```

Comment: You guys are awesome!  Saved me hours on this project!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you could please select this as the correct answer, I am trying to build up my reputation and it would help a lot. Thanks!